# Parsing JSON Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have php on my server that is handling the AJAX call and returning a JSON object like so:

```
$dataArray = array('order_id'=>$order_id, 'response'=>'Sucessfully Added');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $dataArray );
```

This is my AJAX call:

```
$('.add').ajaxForm({url: this.href, type:'post',
    data: this.serialize,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseText){
        var p = JSON.parse(responseText);
        alert(p.response);
        $('.popupContainer').hide();
    } 
});
```

In FireBug I can see that it reaches the line that begins with 'var p' just fine. In fact, at this point, FB tells me that the responseText is exactly what I want it to be: `{"order_id":"182","response":"Sucessfully Added"}`. But at that point it suddenly stops, so I must be missing something here.

Comment: `var p = JSON.parse(responseText);` likely isn't what you want.

Comment: try `this.serialize()` instead of `this.serialize`, and also you don't need to parse the JSON, the response should be a JSON object already

Comment: Why the down-votes? This is legitimate confusion…I spent an hour going through webpages and didn't find anyone pointing out this issue… :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do manual parsing, since the `dataType` is set as `json` the response will be automatically parsed

```
$('.add').ajaxForm({
    url: this.href,
    type: 'post',
    data: this.serialize,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (p) {
        alert(p.response);
        $('.popupContainer').hide();
    }
});
```

[jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)

**dataType**

> 'json': if dataType == 'json' the server response will be evaluted and
>   passed to the 'success' callback, if specified

**success**

> responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the
>   dataType option).